# Adding Attributes Filter To Log in History Manager

Tags: ibm-information-server

We just enabled the history manager to replace the UDL.

We created a filter so that only a few of the catalogs will use the history manager, otherwise the database will fill up to quick.

Is it possible to also add a filter on what attributes to log in the history manager, instead of all attributes?

(For example we have some audit info in the items that we do not want to be logged).

Answer (score 0):

No OOTB way. Couple of workarounds

- Write a Before Trigger on INSERTS into history table and muzzle the
  attributes you don't want to persist. Note, the input here will be an
  XML so need to traverse through
- A scheduled report to rewrite history records by traversing each record and removing values for unwanted attributes.